# Repeat commands

Tags: windows, command

I am looking for a way to repeat commands in Windows. Does any one know how to do it?

Just a example, I have 20 windows open and I want in all of them to press "Alt" "I" "B" "Enter" "Ctrl+V" "Enter". Not necessarily all windows at the same time.

Comment: Have a look to T-planRobot http://www.t-plan.com/robot/index.html. May help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try an app which can record macros e.g. [Ghost Control](http://www.ghost-control.com/).

Try to understand how the program works and record `"Alt" "I" "B" "Enter" "Ctrl+V"`  and `"Alt+Tab"` to switch to the next window.

Save the "script" and run in as many times as you want, even an infinite loop is possible.

I hope it helps.